# Stopping label replacement

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

I am creating a revision program for myself however whenever the fun1 function is called it prints out underneath the previously executed function. e.g the label will print out underneath the last one instead of replacing it, any ideas? Any help would be appreciated!!

```
#Imports moduals used
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

#Sets GUI
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("500x500")
gui.maxsize(width=500, height=500)
gui.minsize(width=500, height=500)



#Sets list of facts
def t():
    print("hi")
facts = ['fact one','true', 'fact two','abc']

#Defines random fact generator
def fun1():
    r = random.randrange(len(facts))
    lbl = Label(gui,text=facts[r]).pack()
    btnt = Button(text="True", command=t).pack()
    btnf = Button(text="False", command=t).pack()
    gui.after(5000, fun1)

gui.after(5000, fun1)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

The best way to write this sort of program is to create the label or button only once, and then use the `configure` method to change the text of the the label.

## Using a procedural style

Here's an example based off of your original code:

```
#Imports moduals used
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

#Sets GUI
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("500x500")
gui.maxsize(width=500, height=500)
gui.minsize(width=500, height=500)

def t():
    print("hi")

#Defines random fact generator
def fun1():
    r = random.randrange(len(facts))
    lbl.configure(text=facts[r])
    gui.after(5000, fun1)

#Sets list of facts
facts = ['fact one','true', 'fact two','abc']

# create the widgets
lbl = Label(gui,text="")
btnt = Button(text="True", command=t)
btnf = Button(text="False", command=t)

# lay out the widgets
lbl.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
btnt.pack(side="left", fill="x")
btnf.pack(side="right", fill="y")

# show the first fact; it will cause other
# facts to show up every N seconds
fun1()

mainloop()
```

## Using an object-oriented style

Since you're just getting started, let me suggest a better way to organize your code. Python is object-oriented in nature, so it makes sense to make your application an object. Even though you may not be familiar with classes an objects, if you start with this pattern and follow a couple of simple rules, you can get all the benefits of object orientation without much effort.

The only thing you need to remember is that in your main class, all functions need to have `self` as the first parameter, and when calling a function you use `self.function` and *omit* `self` as an argument (python does that for you). Other than that, you can pretty much code as normal inside a class.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.facts = ['fact one','true', 'fact two','abc', 'a long fact\non two lines']

        self.label = tk.Label(self,text="", width = 40, height=4)
        self.true_button = tk.Button(self, text="True", command=self.t)
        self.false_button = tk.Button(self, text="False", command=self.t)

        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, pady=40)
        self.true_button.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        self.false_button.pack(side="right", fill="x")

        self.fun1()

    def t(self):
        print("hi")

    def fun1(self):
        r = random.randrange(len(self.facts))
        self.label.configure(text=self.facts[r])
        self.after(5000, self.fun1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here are a few things to notice:

1. `import tkinter as tk` this requires a tiny bit more typing, but it makes your program more robust. The side effect of this (which is a good side effect IMO) is that all tkinter commands now need to be prefixed with `tk` (eg: `tk.Button`). In my opinion this is a much better way than just blindly importing everything from tkinter as a bunch of global variables and functions. I know must tutorials show `from tkinter import *`, but they are misguided.
2. The main part of your logic is a class. This makes it easy to avoid using global variables. As a rule of thumb when programming, you should avoid global variables.
3. Notice how `self` is an argument to `t`, `fun1` and `__init__` -- this is a requirement for python classes. It's just how you do it. Also notice we call them like `self.fun1` rather than just `fun1`. This lets python know that you want to call the function associated with the current object. Once your program gets bigger, this makes it easier to know where `fun1` is defined.
4. I removed the code that forces the size of the GUI. Tkinter is really good at calculating what the size should be, so let it do it's job. Also, if you take care when laying out your widgets, they will grow and shrink properly when the window is resized. This means you don't need to force a min or max size to a window. Forcing a size gives a bad user experience -- users should always be able to resize windows to fit their needs.
5. I separated the creation of the widgets from the layout of the widgets. For one, you *have* to separate them if you want to keep references to widgets. This is because this: `lbl=label(...).pack()` sets lbl to `None`. That's just how python works -- the last function is what gets saved to a variable, and both `pack` and `grid` always return none. The second reason is simply that it makes your code easier to write and maintain. All of the code that organizes your widgets is in one place, making it easier to see the big picture.